# access_token for Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I want to get a **access_token** to get information from **Google Analytics API** by passing it in the browser . I am not able to find the correct documentation anywhere. I have tried multiple ways but nothing seems to work. As of now, I got tokens via Google Analytics Query Explorer and it works for 60 minutes. I am looking for a permanent token or a token which is valid for a more period of time.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  Have you checked though the quickstarts? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

Comment: I am just passing it via browser . query looks like this - https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A276767676&start-date=2020-12-07&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&access_token=*****

Comment: Thats because you need an access token.   Which you cant just request via a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access private Google analytics data you need to be authorized.  In order to be authorized you use something called [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

The initial request will look something like this.  It will allow the user to consent to your applications access to their data

```
GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={clientid}.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly&response_type=code
```

Once the user has consented to your accessing their data, you will be given an authorization code.

Once you have the authorization code you can exchange it for an access token.  This is a http post request.

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code=4/X9lG6uWd8-MMJPElWggHZRzyFKtp.QubAT_P-GEwePvB8fYmgkJzntDnaiAI&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

The response should then look something like this.

```
{
"access_token" : "ya29.1.AADtN_VSBMC2Ga2lhxsTKjVQ_ROco8VbD6h01aj4PcKHLm6qvHbNtn-_BIzXMw",
"token_type" : "Bearer",
"expires_in" : 3600,
"refresh_token" : "1/J-3zPA8XR1o_cXebV9sDKn_f5MTqaFhKFxH-3PUPiJ4"
}
```

The access token will work for one hour.

I recommend looking for a sample and a client library in your chosen programming language so that you dont have to do all this manually most of the libraries are designed to handle authentication and authorization for you.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py  I followed this page and it worked like a charm. Thank you for helping me out :)